# Configure MailEnable for SSL error: Server does not support secure connections

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, windows-server-2016

I send emails from my Windows Server 2016 VPS via mailhost `localhost`, using MailEnable.
using this code it all works:

```
Dim mailObj As New SmtpClient
mailObj.Host = "localhost"
mailObj.Port = 25
```

However, when I try to send email over SSL I get the error:

> Server does not support secure connections.

- I opened SMTP port 587 in the Windows Firewall
- I got SSL certificates for domains and assigned to MailEnable: example.com,www.example.com,smtp.example.com,mail.example.com,ftp.example.com,pop.example.com
- Configured MailEnable, also to use the above certificate

My code on the backend:

```
Dim mailObj As New SmtpClient
mailObj.Host = "localhost"
mailObj.EnableSsl = True
mailObj.Port = 587
mailObj.UseDefaultCredentials = false
mailObj.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@example.com", "mypwd")
```

When I check `Enable TLS` in the 1st screenshot below I get error:

> Failure sending mail.

This is the log I get with `Enable TLS` enabled:

```
[06/23/20 22:33:31]****************** LOG FILE STARTED *******************
06/23/20 22:33:31   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:31   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:32   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:32   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:33   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:33   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:33   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.60.249.12], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:34   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.70.149.50], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:34   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [185.143.72.34], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:34   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:35   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:35   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:36   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:37   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:37   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:37   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153          220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:37   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:37   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  30  casino@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:38   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [185.143.75.153], this server offers 5 extensions   144 11      
06/23/20 22:33:38   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  30  fourier@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:38   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:38   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:38   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  30  salud@example.com   
06/23/20 22:33:39   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:39   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   AUTH    bGV0bWVpbg==    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  casino@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:39   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   AUTH    Rk9VUklFUg==    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  fourier@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:39   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.70.149.18], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   AUTH    UEBzc3cwcmQ=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  salud@example.com   
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN BDFF4AEDD8B94D0987166BA0DEAC1FC0.MAI    1060    185.143.72.34   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   fourier@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:40   SMTP-IN A4C36F71EB8A4F0C8708CD88F4DF3671.MAI    1020    212.60.249.12   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   casino@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:41   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  26  sa2@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:41   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  30  mytime@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:41   SMTP-IN FFD462EEB67B44159FF086464B9D3C5E.MAI    1036    212.70.149.50   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   salud@example.com   
06/23/20 22:33:42   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  AUTH    MTExMQ==    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  10  sa2@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:42   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   AUTH    bXl0aW1lMDE=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  mytime@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:43   SMTP-IN D50DB0BE07584F9484734E4E911EE303.MAI    1104    185.143.75.153  QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   sa2@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:43   SMTP-IN 09B37BA353F34F3EA5A98E682F9E963C.MAI    1120    212.70.149.18   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   mytime@example.com  
06/23/20 22:33:45   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:45   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:46   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [185.143.75.81], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:47   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:48   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:49   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  38  unbansubmit@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:50   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2            220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:50   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:50   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   AUTH    cEBzc3cwcmQ=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  unbansubmit@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:51   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.70.149.2], this server offers 5 extensions 142 11      
06/23/20 22:33:51   SMTP-IN CA6566ED0D5C4CF4BC9EA6A1A5AC988B.MAI    1068    185.143.75.81   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   unbansubmit@example.com 
06/23/20 22:33:52   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:53   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:54   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:33:54   0   0       
06/23/20 22:33:54   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  34  edamamur@example.com    
06/23/20 22:33:55   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    AUTH    ZWRhbWFtdXI=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  edamamur@example.com    
06/23/20 22:33:55   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [185.143.72.25], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:33:56   SMTP-IN CB468621E3BC48089B6A50F14530F7F9.MAI    1136    212.70.149.2    QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   edamamur@example.com    
06/23/20 22:33:56   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:33:58   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:33:59   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  26  ns43@example.com    
06/23/20 22:34:00   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   AUTH    MTIzNDU2Nzg=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  ns43@example.com    
06/23/20 22:34:01   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:34:01   0   0       
06/23/20 22:34:01   SMTP-IN B4699D1493B74E85A8671850B09F08D3.MAI    1112    185.143.72.25   QUIT    QUIT    221 Service closing transmission channel    42  6   ns43@example.com    
06/23/20 22:34:02   SMTP-IN 3FE80CCEAA0942739F26259F1FB15696.MAI    1040    212.60.249.12           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 7.59-7.59- ready at 06/23/20 22:34:02   0   0       
06/23/20 22:34:02   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.70.149.50], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:34:03   SMTP-IN 3FE80CCEAA0942739F26259F1FB15696.MAI    1040    212.60.249.12   EHLO    EHLO User   250-example.com [212.60.249.12], this server offers 5 extensions    143 11      
06/23/20 22:34:04   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:34:05   SMTP-IN 3FE80CCEAA0942739F26259F1FB15696.MAI    1040    212.60.249.12   RSET    RSET    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  6       
06/23/20 22:34:05   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:34:06   SMTP-IN 3FE80CCEAA0942739F26259F1FB15696.MAI    1040    212.60.249.12   AUTH    AUTH LOGIN  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    18  12      
06/23/20 22:34:07   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  22  x@example.com   
06/23/20 22:34:08   SMTP-IN 3FE80CCEAA0942739F26259F1FB15696.MAI    1040    212.60.249.12   AUTH    {blank} 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    18  30  marvin@example.com  
06/23/20 22:34:08   SMTP-IN 9CBF0EE9385B47DE8E869EAFE6CC220D.MAI    1100    212.70.149.50   AUTH    UEBzc3cwcmQ=    504 Invalid Username or Password    34  14  x@example.com   
[06/23/20 22:34:09]****************** LOG FILE CLOSED ********************
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, I disabled require SSL for inbound port 587
I checked Enable TLS on general settings tab

I'm however missing a checkbox `Allow clients to establish secure sessions via STARTTLS`  as can be seen [here](https://www.slasi.nl/nl/blog/how-to-configure-mailenable-to-work-with-ssl).

The mail is now sent when I've set `EnableSsl` to `false`.

Now. I however see when I try to send an email from info@example.com via smtp.example.com

`Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.`

I tried using the same credentials for info@example.com, but those don't work. Should I configure different credentials somewhere?

**UPDATE 2**
Upgraded and checked `Allow clients to establish secure sessions via STARTTLS`.
On the latest MailEnable version there however is no longer a setting `Enable TLS` on the [General] tab.
I still get the error:

> Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

I tried sending via `localhost` without anycredentials (that email works) and via `smtp.example.com` with credentials, in which case it fails.
I think though I need to send via `smtp.example.com` because I have an SSL certificate for that domain, whereas when I send via `localhost` I need an SSL certificate for my VPS server domain `648gfhur343.stratserver.net`, which is not possible (because issued via Let's Encrypt, different issue).

**SMTP LOG**

```
[06/27/20 14:17:27]****************** LOG FILE STARTED *******************
06/27/20 14:17:29   SMTP-IN A7DFBF7F65344DCD86F1FE13AC92DD20.MAI    844 212.60.249.12           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 10.30-- ready at 06/27/20 14:17:29  94  0       
06/27/20 14:17:30   SMTP-IN 21CF95A9113A47B581E1F0C4FDEB146A.MAI    840 85.214.200.31           220 mail.example.com ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 10.30-- ready at 06/27/20 14:17:30  94  0       
06/27/20 14:17:30   SMTP-IN 21CF95A9113A47B581E1F0C4FDEB146A.MAI    840 85.214.200.31   EHLO    EHLO h2746286   250-example.com [85.214.200.30], this server offers 5 extensions    237 15      
06/27/20 14:17:30   SMTP-IN 21CF95A9113A47B581E1F0C4FDEB146A.MAI    840 85.214.200.31   MAIL    MAIL FROM:<info@example.com>    250 Requested mail action okay, completed   43  34      
06/27/20 14:17:30   SMTP-IN 21CF95A9113A47B581E1F0C4FDEB146A.MAI    840 85.214.200.31   RCPT    RCPT TO:<myname@gmail.com>  503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.   235 33      
[06/27/20 14:17:36]****************** LOG FILE CLOSED ********************
```

**Screenshots settings**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableSsl doesn't actually use SSL to connect to the mail server, but connects without SSL and uses the STARTTLS command to then move to a secure communication. You need to select the "Enable TLS" checkbox, which then allows the service to support the STARTTLS command but turn off the "Requires SSL" for the 587 port configuration (or use port 25 where SSL is not used).

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, but still it doesn't work. I added update 1, could you have a look please?

Comment: I suggest upgrading your version of the mail server. I am not sure how to enable it in your version, but the checkbox was added there in 7.61. Your version is 6 years old, and you'd benefit from the changes and security fixes. If you go to the download page for the software there is a link towards the bottom for the older versions, and you can get the upgrade to 7.63. This can be installed over the top of your version.